# Last words before death

Tags: death

Hello I have been trying to find thr answer to this question on islam stack exchange google everyrhingof this question a lot and havent found an answer.

question:Should i say la il a ha illalahu before i pass away or ashhadu an la ila ha

Answer (score 1):

The hadith does not mentioned "Ash-hadu An." It only mentions "Laa Ilaaha Illa Allah."

> Exhort to recite "لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ (There is no god but Allah)" to those of you who are dying. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/11/3))

However, I don't think adding "Ash-hadu An" makes much of a difference. It simply means "I testify that." It places emphasis on the statement.

Even when you add it, your last words are still "Laa Ilaaha Illa Allah."

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you say: If your heart is loving Allah HE will receive you with joy. Because Allah knows our hearts. May Allah bless you

p.s. I wonder who voted down my answer. I have seen many persons close to death. Most of them were no more able to utter a word at the end. Yes, of course, you can say words according to sharia if you are fully present. But if it happens and your last words were different, this is nothing important. That is what I say.

Comment: Yes you right... Passing the life with Iman till the last period is the root thing... Allah is the most merciful...

Answer (score 0):

Saying La Ilaha illallah is a good sign that we know from a hadith of "Abu Daud" amongst the Sihah Sittah. But that is only the luckiest peoples. But people not saying this may be included this luckiest part... People who are deaf, paralyzed with a side of forebrain are not able to speak. Again we know muslim people who die in accident, thunder or in a pandemic gain the value of "Shahada".

In general it is only a few lucky people who can recite people at the time during death. Muslims who are righteous but can't recite Shahada at the time of his death is not a bad sign and we have nothing to worry about him if he is truly righteous during his lifetime.

In the hadith which says people who declare Shahada before their death are only a few people of Divine people of the Akhirat...